# Stop partial form redirect after submission?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a View which contains two partial views:

**Both.cshtml**

```
<div id="first">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Example/_FirstForm.cshtml")
</div>
<div id="second">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Example/_SecondForm.cshtml")
</div>
```

Each of those partials simply contain a different form, each executing a different action.

**_FirstForm.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("First", "Example", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))

... form stuff
```

**_SecondForm.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Second", "Example", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))

... form stuff
```

**The problem:**

When I submit one of the above forms I want to call the form action (either `First` or `Second`), but stay on the same page I called it from (in this case `Both.cshtml`).

Currently, If I submit the First Form, it takes me to `/Example/First`, which doesn't exist and I get a 404. Same for the second form but `/Example/Second`.

I plan to use these partial View forms on other pages also, so I wouldn't just like to do a return `View("Both.cshtml");`. I just want the action to be called and for the same full `View()` that the partial is featured on to be shown.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: On the outset, you can use Ajax.BeginForm to submit the partial forms via Ajax.  However, it sounds like you want submission of either form to actually post to a different action?

Comment: @BrendanGreen Yep, I'd like the respective forms to trigger the First and Second actions, without attempting to go to these non-existent /Example/First and /Example/Second pages

Comment: First of all..fix your paragraph vocabulary which makes no sense to me ..what the problem ans waht your trying to achieve...

Comment: @Shaz I am using multiple partial views in the same view. Each partial view contains a form. When I submit that form I want to call the form action, but stay on the same page I called it from.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

1. When one of the two forms on Both is submitted, you'll hit either the One or Two action methods. Inside these methods, redirect back to Both
2. Ajax submit the forms: this will send the data back to the action methods on the server, and you can (depending on your needs), either send some markup back to redraw the contents of your form, or simply send back some Json to indicate success/failure

Based on your comment, option 2 would look something like this:

```
var postForm = function(formId) {
    var $form = $('#' + formId);
    var action = $form.attr('action');
    var postBody = $form.serialize();

    $.post(action, postBody).done(function(data) {
        // do something with any data you may have returned from the server
        // could be html markup, could simply be a success/error flag
    });
}
```

This will allow you to serialize either of your forms and submit to the correct action without refreshing your page. It's important to note that any results returned from your First/Second actions will be in the 'data' param on the .done call.

Comment: 1. This would be fine, however as mentioned I'll be using the partials on other pages too, so it can't be Both.cshtml specific. 2. I'll try look into this but I don't know much about that

Comment: ah...I misunderstood what you meant. I thought you simply were reusing the views, and not the Action also.

Comment: Other than not redirecting to First/Second upon submit, do you need to change anything on the page based on the server's response, or do you essentially want nothing to change on the page?

Comment: As long as it performs the action, e.g. calls 'First' or 'Second' in my controller, doing nothing else is fine, as the controller actions have all the stuff I need

Answer (score 0):

In that case do not use submitt button type in any of the partial...as it will execute from post instead use Jquery to validate which button is pressed and submitt that form..

for example

```
<form name= "form1" id ="form1" action ="abc.php" method="post">
<input type ="button" id="mybutton" value ="Submitt">
</form>
```

**************java script*******************************

```
$("#mybutton").click(function() {
            $('#form1').submit();
});
```

regards

## shaz